# Mule Aggregate large amounts of data

Tags: mule

I have a delimited file that I split in Mule and process async. I then aggregate each response using the collection-aggregator which works fine.

But in production environment, this file will be huge and it will be a problem trying to aggregate all the results into a collection in memory.

Is there another way to aggregate massive amounts of data in mule without holding all this data in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like that out of the box.
Probably, the ideal thing would be to leverage the new [Scatter Gather](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/EARLYACCESS/Scatter-Gather) with a custom-aggregation-strategy that stores in disk rather than in memory.